# Bootstrap 4 tabbed content not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to make a tabbed content with Bootstrap 4, which is very new to me. Here is what i have so far:

```css
.tabbed-sidebar {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.tabbed-sidebar .tabbed-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.tabbed-sidebar .nav-tabs {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.tabbed-sidebar .nav-tabs li {
 -webkit-flex: 1;
 -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 1px;
}

.tabbed-sidebar .nav-tabs li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #565656;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tabbed-sidebar .nav-tabs li a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;
}

.tabbed-sidebar .tabs-content {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tabbed-sidebar">
  <div class="tabbed-heading">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a class="active" href="#popular" data-toggle="tab">Popular</a></li>
      <li><a href="#video" data-toggle="tab">Video</a></li>
      <li><a href="#topcomments" data-toggle="tab">Top comments</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="popular">
      sqxq  
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="video">
      ssss
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="topcomments">
      dddd
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

There are **2 problems** with this "tabbed content" as far as I can see:

1. The content corresponding to the **active tab** is not reveled on document load;
2. The content corresponding to the **inactive tabs** is not gradually hidden (faded out). Instead, its opacity is set to 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First issue:** *The content corresponding to the active tab is not reveled on document load*

From [Boostrap 4 Official Documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#fade-effect)

> To make tabs fade in, add .fade to each .tab-pane. The first tab pane must also have **.show** to make the initial content visible.

Try this

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show in active" id="popular">
```

**Second issue:** *The content corresponding to the inactive tabs is not gradually hidden (faded out). Instead, its opacity is set to 0.*

In Bootstrap the .fade transition time is 0.15s, so you just need adjust it to your wishes. Ex:

**CSS:**

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.15s linear;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var current = e.target.getAttribute('href');
  var prev = e.relatedTarget.getAttribute('href');
  $(current).show();
  $(prev).hide();
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn5sedh9/1)

Comment: @RazvanZamfir The fade effect is working well, but I added an exemple if you want increase the transition time

Comment: I want then to disappear (`style="display: none"`) slowly, *not* reduce opacity to 0.

Comment: The `display` is a discrete property, doesn't work with CSS transition or animation

Comment: Do I have a jQuery alternative to this, that *can be used in this context*?

Comment: Your fiddle has the same problem as mine.